# Javascript getElementById based on ID formed using fixed name and input number

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create ID dynamically in the HTML object and use of getElementById() in my javascript to access the HTML input value based on the button I clicked and insert into their respective HTML Select list.

My HTML snippets:

```
<input type="text" id="addDesc1"><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDescText(1)"> 
<input type="text" id="addDesc2"><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDescText(2)">
....
....
<select id="desc1">....</select>
<select id="desc2">....</select>
```

My javascript snippets:

```
function addDescText(id) {
    var descText = document.getElementById("addDesc".concat(id)).value;
    var selList = document.getElementById("desc".concat(id));
    ....
    ....
    some javascript to add the respective description to their respective select list
    ....
}
```

Comment: don't use `"desc".concat(id)`. Do either `"desc" + id` , or `\`desc${id}\``

Comment: `document.getElementById("addDesc"+id)` or with es2015's template variables like **document.getElementById(``addDesc${id}``)**

Comment: You could do this by getting the element that performed the click (this will be available through the [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event)).  Then once you have that getting the other elements can be done using accessing [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling).

Answer (score 1):

[**`concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is an array method, you can not use that on string. Simply use `+` to concatenate the parameter with the string.

**Demo:**

```js
function addDescText(id) {
  var descText = document.getElementById("addDesc"+id).value;
  var selList = document.getElementById("desc"+id);

  console.log(descText);
  console.log(selList);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addDesc1"><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDescText(1)"> 
<input type="text" id="addDesc2"><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDescText(2)">

<select id="desc1">....</select>
<select id="desc2">....</select>
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but it did not worked.. I had tried again and confirmed it did not worked for the 2nd or 3rd "Add" button. The first one will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to make use of the event parameter that is passed to all event handlers (on-click-event in your case) and add that handler programmatically.

A possible solution would be

HTML

```html
  <input type="text" id="text1">
  <input type="button" value="Add" class="add-desc-button" data-target="1">
```

JS

```js
// get all buttons
let allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-desc-button')

// add event handler
for (let i=0; i<allButtons.length; i++) {
  allButtons[i].addEventHandler('click', addDescriptionHandler)
}

// event handler
function addDescriptionHandler(event) {
   // retrieve the number you passed in before like this
   let number = event.target.getAttribute('data-target')
   // ... your code here
}
```